# Question about Google's repo tool filed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, off-topic

This question is about a less widely know tool, repo, used for development of the Android Open Source Project.

[Android source code and repo - What exactly is happening when getting code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15870217/102937)

I'm not sure how this question is off topic in the least -- especially because it was closed without any comments.  I'm not mad or anything (obligatory comment because I have the accepted answer); I'm just curious.  Is there something in the question its self or the answer that has dragged the question into the off topic realm?  The only explanation I can come up with is the people responsible for closing it are unfamiliar with Google's repo tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The only explanation I can come up with is the people responsible for closing it are unfamiliar with Google's repo tool.

That, or they're unfamiliar with source control, so they closed it assuming it wasn't a programmer-y thing. I reopened it.

Comment: Cool cool.  I assumed as much (=